# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after moved to new servers

Tags: java, tomcat8, noclassdeffounderror

We have some old application which is giving issue once we moved to new DC. 
We have some url's which fetches out document for you from server, now we are getting the issue while connecting to server once we hit that url.

I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError`, I checked the war file but I can see respective dependency is already there.

> SEVERE [http-nio-4003-exec-9]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Session_Manager] in context with path [/xyz] threw
>   exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class abc.pqr

NOTE : we moved this setup from windows server to linux

Could you please guide me on the same.

Comment: what's `abc.pqr`?

Comment: that is just dummy name I added

Comment: Where is that class in the old deployment?

Comment: that class is under jar file which is already under lib directory for tomcat. So looks everything is there as per required things

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are any jars added to the Tomcat files themselves so they are readily available to all applications.  Those need to be copied too.

Comment: yes checked and all are there same as old server, will verify once again. Thank you:)

Comment: Otherwise deobfuscate your Exception stack trace.